# Why does GetWindowRgn fail on Vista?

Tags: winapi, windows-vista

I'm writing a program that uses [`SetWindowRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102(VS.85).aspx) to make transparent holes in a window that belongs to another process. (This is done only when the user explicitly requests it.)

The program has to assume that the target window may already have holes which need to be preserved, so before it calls `SetWindowRgn`, it calls [`GetWindowRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144950(VS.85).aspx) to get the current region, then combines the current region with the new one and calls `SetWindowRgn`:

```
HRGN rgnOld = CreateRectRgn ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
int regionType = GetWindowRgn ( hwnd, rgnOld );
```

This works fine in XP, but the call to `GetWindowRgn` fails in Vista. I've tried turning off Aero and elevating my thread's privilege to `SE_DEBUG_NAME` with [`AdjustTokenPrivileges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375202(VS.85).aspx), but neither helps.

GetLastError() doesn't seem to return a valid value for GetWindowRgn -- it returns 0 on one machine and 5 (Access denied) on another.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest a different approach?

Comment: If the MSDN does not say explicitly that you can call GetLastError() to obtain more details about the error, GetLastError() will return a random value. You could call SetLastError(1234) before GetWindowRgn() and GetLastError() will always return 1234 afterwards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure your window *has* a region? Most top-level windows in XP do, simply because the default theme uses them for round corners... but this is still a bad assumption to be making, and may very well not hold once you get to Vista.

If you haven't set a region yet, and the call fails, use a sensible default (the window rect) and don't let it ruin your life. Now, if `SetWindowRgn()` fails...

Comment: Thank you Shog.  You nailed it.  I was assuming (without realizing it) that windows always have regions.

I rewrote it. Now, when GetWindowRgn fails, it sets a region based on the window rect.  Works perfectly.

This is the best answer I've gotten on a forum in a long time.  /salute

Answer (score 2):

Under Vista, in order for a process that does not run as administrator to target a window from another process, it must:

- Embed a manifest file with uiAccess="true" (example below)
- Digitally sign the application
- Install and execute it from a "safe" place, like "Program Files"

Here's a sample manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" name="yourAssemblyNameWithoutExtension" type="win32"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: As Freddie so nicely pointed it out, this does not answer HIS problem. This manifest is required if you are targettting elevated or isolated (e.g. IE7) processes from a non-elevated process.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you're trying to get the region of the window of **another process**. Vista tightened up the security of a lot of cross-process Win32 calls. I can't find any documentation one way or the other for `GetWindowRgn()`, but you could test it simply enough. Make a simple project that sets it's own region, and try to use your original app to get the simple app's region. If it works, then it's just going to be annoying and people can't use your app on just anything. If it doesn't work, there's a chance that your app won't work at all on Vista.

Comment: I did test on my own app. It was the first thing I did.  Also, as I mentioned (with an unfortunate typo) I elevated privilege level to debug.

Also, I knew when I posted earlier that SetWindowRgn works fine in Vista.  I thought it was unlikely that Vista allows setting but disallows getting.

Answer (score 1):

---

### My answer (based on my experience) regarding the Windows API function ::GetWindowRgn(...)

This function fails in Vista and in Windows 7, that is, it returns ERROR.

But this function works good in Windows XP.

Therefore, I would advice the following non-complex solution:
  If you use this function within an application expected to run
  under different Windows, provide the test like this:
    int nResultOfRgnOperation = ::GetWindowRegion(...);
    if (nResultOfRgnOperation != ERROR)
      < Use further the entire window's region determined by this function >
    else
      < Find the bounding rectangle for the entire window and use
        further that bounding rectangle instead of the window's region.
        In needed, you can create a rectangular region which represents
        the bounding rectangle. >

Please use corresponding code in the places marked above as <...>

Thank you for your enthusiasm.

---